# firestore is not working with React Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I installed firebase with react native expo using `expo add firebase`, then
I created a file (firebase.tsx) and added the Firebase configuration and initialized the app like in this screenshot with correct values].

[image: like in this image with correct values]

I have added the google-services.json and
GoogleService-info.plist to the root of my expo project like the documentation say and i am importing firebase in my api service like this `import Firebase from './../../../firebase'`.

In my register function I call the firebase create user function

```
const response = await Firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email.value, values.password.value)
```

The response is never returned, and if I use . then nothing happens either.
If I log firebase.auth I get an object with my API key and app name, etc. so Firebase is installed, but whenever I call the database for sign in or to access a collection nothing happens.

This is my package.json.

[image: This is my package.json]

This is my app.json.

[image: This is my app.json]

I added bundleIdentifier and googleServicesFile to iOS and package and googleServicesFile for Android.

Comment: I have a similar issue (but with a bare setup for expo, and using rnfirebase.io). Seems to be caused by expo-application in my case. Difficult to say because it is intermittent.

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are getting but you should import Firebase like this: `import firebase from "firebase/app"`

Answer (score 1):

currently **Firebase** seems not to be working in **expo** if you are using the android configuration. I have tried the web configuration and it has worked for me. Here is the [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hPgQWbWmEk&t=3309s) for it. Watch from `38:20` to set up.